How to tell comint on start which directory to use?
I am using lua-mode for interacting with the Lua repl, which is built on top of comint.  Unfortunately, it does not seem that running a lua repl from a buffer correctly sets the directory of the spawned REPL, which makes it impossible to for example require modules easily.
I was wondering if there is a way to tell comint on start which directory to use.  I can change the directory afterwards manually using "M-x cd", but I felt surely there must be a way to make sure this is set on start?  Especially if I spawn comint from a buffer that is visiting a file, it seems natural that the directory should be set to the file's directory.
This does not seem like a rare or unusual use case, so I am wondering how other people solve this?  My only idea so far is to create a macro that

gets the directory of the current buffer
starts comint
switches to the comint buffer
run "cd" with the directory

How can I tell comint on start which directory to use?

I know nothing about Lua. How do I reproduce this problem? Please provide a step-by-step guide suitable for a noob. I don't think comint is the problem though: other REPLs work fine.

Well, the way I see it - if I run comint, the comint process starts with ~ as a home directory. You can verify that by running comint and selecting e.g. "bash" as the process.  I was hoping you could adjust that so that the spawned process can have a different CWD, so it can more easilty interact with my buffers / files.

There is no such thing as the comint process: M-x comint-run executes a function that asks what you want to run. You then say lua or bash and then the function calls the OS fork system call to create a process running lua or bash or whatever. If I run M-x comint-run RET bash RET with my default-directory being /tmp,  then bash will start and its current working directory will be /tmp. I am expecting the same thing to happen when you start lua but I don't know how to check, so I was hoping you could tell me how.

IOW, try M-x cd RET /path/to/wherever/you/want/lua/to/start RET in some buffer and then from that same buffer say M-x comint-run RET lua RET - does that work?

Ok it must be something in my configuration - if I do this with a "stock" emacs (using -q), it works! So now I am off debugging my config :/
Thanks for your help!
